# Шаблонная функция работает очень долго

Tags: c++

Шаблонная функция для конвертации байт в какой-то из стандартных типов работает очень долго (отладчик VS2019 показывал 60-90мс). Я не совсем понимаю в чем дело.

Сама функция (не уверен что vector тут уместен, но это как набросок):

```
typedef uint8_t byte;

template<typename T>
T bytes_to_type(vector<byte> buf, uint32_t pos, const char* endian = "little")
{
    uint8_t size = sizeof(T);
    T value = 0;
    if (strcmp(endian, "big"))
        for (uint8_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
            *((byte*)&value + i) = buf[pos + size - i - 1];
    else
        for (uint8_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
            *((byte*)&value + i) = buf[pos + i];

    return value;
}
```

Вызываю же ее из другой функции вот так:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < tracks_count; i++)
{
    int pos = 1536 + track_length * 4 + i * track_length * 4 + (i + 1) * 44;
    for (size_t j = start_pos; j < track_length; j++)
        all_amplitudes[i][j] = bytes_to_type<float>(byte_array, pos + j * 4);
}
```

Насколько я знаю, экземпляры шаблонных функций получаются на этапе компиляции. Но может ли быть такое, что компилятор не определил какой экземпляр ему нужен и функция получается во время выполнения программы ?

Comment: Не по сути вопроса - но зачем передавать порядок байт строкой? 8-/ Передавайте `bool`, этого достаточно. Возможно, даже как параметр шаблона.

Comment: Я вдохновлялся питоном скажем так )) И да, я это перепишу

Comment: Передача вектора по значению в такой простой функции - это уже дико долго. Да и сам факт завязки на вектор в такой задаче - это уже "долго", независимо от способа передачи.

Comment: std::byte ? не ? Хотя да давайте писать на С++ и работать с байтами в char*

Comment: Да и вообще дичь.....memcpy и обратиться к T val; через & не ????